# Declaring many variables in a loop

Tags: java, variables, loops, initialization, declaration

so here's my example code of what I'm trying to do (it doesn't compile):

```
    for(char name = 'a'; name <= 'z'; name++)
    {
        double <<name>>;
    }
```

In this example I want to create 26 different variables, without explicitly listing

```
double a, b, c, d, e; //and so on
```

How can I go about doing that? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This seems like a code smell.

Comment: well to be honest I have very little experience programming, and don't know any better. I am trying to name 100 action listeners for the buttons of a Minesweeper program without listing them- maybe I should use an array.

Comment: So you basically want to create a loop to make a bunch of double values? IE you want 26 doubles and you want to name them a-z and you want to do this via making a loop?

Comment: @JoshuaBicknese If you mean you are wanting to set the action command of 100 buttons you don't need to use action command. I assume you have the buttons in an array and you can also evaluate which button is pressed as objects with e.getSource(). Loop through the button array and check `if (e.getSource() == buttons[i]) {`.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array:

```
double[] vars = new double[26];
int i = 0;
for(char name = 'a'; name <= 'z'; name++)
{
    vars[i++] = name;
}
```

Comment: +1 Arrays make perfect sense here esp. since what OP is attempting is not even possible. And, even **if** it was, the variables can't outlive their scope.

Comment: Of course, if he needs let's say 26 variables (from a to z) he will need an array (or anyother kind of array).

Comment: Ok, now the OP has said his specific usecase, and clearly arrays would be better. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612738/declaring-many-variables-in-a-loop?noredirect=1#comment29113996_19612738)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve your values like variable may be you can use [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)!

```
HashMap<Character,Double> variables = new HashMap<Character,Double>();
for(char name = 'a'; name <= 'z'; name++)
    {
        variables.put(name,"put double value here");
    }
```

Comment: Don't you think it may be confusing for the OP? He is just beginning in programming.

Comment: Ya, I agree it may be but I was just showing workaround for the problem.